# Change Image already on Stage as3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, loader, movieclip

Okay this solution seems to not be findable.

I have a border type image on stage (circular) and I am dynamically loading an image from xml in my document class. I have a place holder image inside the border. Can I replace that image with the one that is dynamically loaded?

Or do I have to addChild and then scale and transform it all through code?

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the place holder image and add the new image into the same container and scale/position it. It is simple to do with code.

```
container.removeChild(placeHolderImage);
container.addChild(newLoadedImage);
newLoadedImage.scaleX = newLoadedImage.scaleY = 1.5;
newLoadedImage.x = 100;
newLoadedImage.y = 100;
```

You can possibly draw into the bitmap data of the image already on screen but I don't see any downsides with just removing the old one and adding the new image.